# React native -> Fetch and display

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, cheerio

I need to fetch and display products into a react native component from this page https://www.herba-market.co.rs/kategorija/proizvodi-na-akciji/
As you can see all products are inside the unordered list with a class 'product'.

I tried to fetch the data with fetch function, set it into state, but I'm not sure how can I use cheerio library there to get proper values. In code below, I fetch date and whole HTML markup is showed, but I don't know how to implement cheerio before and than display only some needed data.

```
class NewsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  fetchData = async() => {

   //response
   const response = await fetch('https://www.herba-market.co.rs/kategorija/proizvodi-na-akciji/');

   // posts
   const posts = await response.text();

    this.setState({data: posts});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //page isLoading
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        {this.state.data}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can help you if you create an example on codesandbox.io

Comment: @MukeshSoni examples offsite are discouraged... the OP can create snippet example right in their question.

Comment: ? I don't get it? Where does it say so? Why shouldn't one use the best way to communicate the problem or solution?

Comment: The url you're fetching returns html and not structured json data. It's basically a webpage and not a Web service that returns properly structured data. You should ask them for a proper API endpoint.